# I can't run jupyter with vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I installed Jupyter:

```
$ jupyter --version
upyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.4
jupyter client   : 6.0.0
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 6.0.0
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

In the browser i can run jupyter, but in the vs code first it ask me a password:

[image]

I changed the password with the comande:

> jupyter notebook password

And in all cases i recive de message:

```
Failed to connect to remote Jupyter notebook.
Check that the Jupyter Server URI setting has a valid running     server specified.
http://localhost:8889/tree
r: request to http://localhost:8889/treelogin? failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8889
```

What's i need do to jupyter runing in my vs-code ?

Comment: So it looks like you're specifying a localhost incorrectly to me. The uri you specify should be something like so:
```http://localhost:8888/?token=6d4d0338502c9d003647b230982a189336c0c59326085b03```, not the URI you see in the browser.

Comment: Additionally if you change your ```python.dataScience.jupyterServerURI``` to just be 'local' or empty, we should start our own copy of jupyter for you.